# Javascript array to JSON array, returns array but puts undefined infront

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
var ORDER = {"Rows":[]};

var data = [];
data[0] = ["0","V",amount[a],valueThree,"","",prcat,"00001","",price,"",Descr];
var dataJSONstring = JSON.stringify(data);
ORDER.Rows[0] += dataJSONstring;
```

Hey there, I'm trying to place the Javascript data array as an array into the JSON "Rows" array. I've tried to stringify it, but whenever I do it does put it into a JSON array, but returns:        **

```
undefined[["","V","2","90000001","","","0001","00001","","12","","Volwassenen"]]
```

How to remove the "undefined"? Can't find out how to do it, any ideas?

Comment: It returns undefined + string, which is what I don't understand.

Comment: What is the end result you actually want?

Comment: I need it to put         `["","V","2","90000001","","","0001","00001","","12","","Volwassenen"]` into the `ORDER.Rows`

Comment: One more question, `var ORDER = {"Rows":[]}`, will it display the JSON array in ORDER now? Will it look like `ORDER = {"Rows":[[example1],[example2]]}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It returns undefined + string, which is what I don't understand

Because `ORDER.Rows[0]` is undefined. You've set `Rows` to an empty array. It has no entry at index 0. So retrieving that entry gives you `undefined`, which when you join it with a string via `+` is converted to `"undefined"` (plus the string).

Remember that `a += b` is effectively `a = a + b` (but without evaluating `a` twice). So your code is effectively

```
ORDER.Rows[0] = ORDER.Rows[0] + dataJSONstring;
```

If you wanted to store the string there, you didn't want `+=`, just `=`:

```
ORDER.Rows[0] = dataJSONstring;
```

Comment: One more question, `var ORDER = {"Rows":[]}`, will it display the JSON array in `ORDER` now?
Will it look like `ORDER = {"Rows":[[example1],[example2]]}`?

Comment: @Preamas: Yes, the **JSON** array will be in `ORDER`, and no it won't look like that. Remember, JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. In your code, you converted an array to JSON, which is a **string**. Then you put that **string** into `Rows`. So you'll get `ORDER = {Rows:["[\"\",\"V\",\"2\",\"90000001\",\"\",\"\",\"0001\",\"00001\",\"\",\"12\",\"\",\"Volwassenen\"]"]}`

Comment: Yeah, some guy edited my post just to remove `Hey there,` and probably downvoted both of us. No clue why. Thanks for the answer.